# Time Interval of 5 minutes in Netezza

Tags: sql, datetime, netezza

I have a datetime column and I have to create a new column which will give me the date and time interval with respect to 5 minutes. (Its a Netezza Platform)

```
Transaction Time    Interval - 5 Min(Expected Output)
2/1/2021 8:46   8:45:00 AM
2/1/2021 8:46   8:45:00 AM
2/1/2021 8:46   8:45:00 AM
2/1/2021 8:46   8:45:00 AM
2/1/2021 8:46   8:45:00 AM
2/1/2021 8:46   8:45:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 9:24   9:20:00 AM
2/1/2021 11:40  11:40:00 AM
2/1/2021 12:54  12:50:00 PM
2/1/2021 13:03  1:00:00 PM
2/1/2021 13:28  1:25:00 PM
2/1/2021 14:15  2:15:00 PM
2/1/2021 14:26  2:25:00 PM
2/1/2021 14:26  2:25:00 PM
2/1/2021 14:51  2:50:00 PM
2/1/2021 15:28  3:25:00 PM
2/1/2021 15:28  3:25:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres a way using `mod`

```sql
select 
   transaction_time
    to_char(
     transaction_time - interval '1 min' * mod(
       date_part('minute', transaction_time), 5), 'HH:MI:SS AM') 
            as "5 min boundary" from tab;

  TRANSACTION_TIME   | 5 min boundary
---------------------+----------------
 2021-02-01 08:46:00 | 08:45:00 AM
 2021-02-01 08:46:00 | 08:45:00 AM
 2021-02-01 08:46:00 | 08:45:00 AM
 2021-02-01 08:46:00 | 08:45:00 AM
 2021-02-01 08:46:00 | 08:45:00 AM
 2021-02-01 08:46:00 | 08:45:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 09:24:00 | 09:20:00 AM
 2021-02-01 11:40:00 | 11:40:00 AM
 2021-02-01 12:54:00 | 12:50:00 PM
 2021-02-01 13:03:00 | 01:00:00 PM
 2021-02-01 13:28:00 | 01:25:00 PM
 2021-02-01 14:15:00 | 02:15:00 PM
 2021-02-01 14:26:00 | 02:25:00 PM
(20 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

One commonly used method is the following:

- Convert the date/time to epoch time (seconds since 1970-01-01).
- Round down to five minutes (which is arithmetic).
- Convert back to a timestamp.

The code is not actually that complicated:

```
select to_timestamp(floor(extract(epoch from transaction_time) / (5*60)) * 5*60 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(YOUR_COL, 'HH:' || extract(minutes from YOUR_COL) / 5 * 5 || ' AM');
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.